# why std::string is not implicitly converted to bool

Tags: c++, string, casting, boolean

Is there a reason why in c++ `std::string` is not implicitly converted to bool? For example

```
std::string s = ""
if (s) { /* s in not empty */ }
```

as in other languages (e.g. python). I think it is tedious to use the `empty` method.

Comment: Because it has no operator `bool()`, because the standard doesn´t require one, because ... how should it be defined? Why is empty false and non-empty true in your opinion?

Comment: Probably because the C++ standard developers don't care too much about the orthogonality of their language constructs. C++ is a very baroque language, and there are many such peculiarities in the language.

Comment: It just isn't (neither does an empty vector evaluate to false, etc.). Perhaps an oversight, but possibly purposefully omitted due to the already high number of implicit conversion bugs that arise.

Comment: @deviantfan: it is not my opinion: it is common in many languages

Comment: Once satisfied with _Why_ , see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2165921/1870232)

Comment: @RuggeroTurra But C++ isn´t like Python, JS & co. If you make conditions based on strings in asm (jumps etc.), the best you get is true everytime because the address is not 0. That´s where C and the C++ originated from, not from dynamic typing etc.etc.

Comment: What bool values should these strings convert to?: `""`, `"0"`, `"1"`, `"a"`, `"true"`, `"false"`, `"T"`, `"yes"`, etc.?

Comment: That line reads to me as "if this string is.... what?"  .size() != 0?  .capacity() != 0?  To me it reads as incomplete.  Then again, I don't like the implicit test on anything other than variables of type `bool`.

Comment: It may be a common feature in many languages, but there certainly isn't a common convention among those languages for which string values should be considered false, and which should be considered true.

Comment: Agree, it would be weird to have `"false"s == true`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This probably *could* be added now that C++11 has added the concepts of explicit conversions and contextual conversion.

When `std::string` was designed, neither of these was present though. That made classes that supported conversion to `bool` fairly difficult to keep safe. In particular, that conversion could (and would) happen in lots of cases you almost never wanted it to. For example, if we assume `std::string` converts to `false` if empty and otherwise to `true`, then you could use a `string` essentially *anywhere* an integer or pointer was intended.

Rather than telling you about the type mismatch, the compiler would convert the string to bool, and then the bool to an integer (false -> 0, true -> 1).

Things like this happened often enough with many early attempts at string types (and there were *many*) that the committee apparently decided it was better to keep implicit conversions to an absolute minimum (so about the only implicit conversion supported by `string` is to create a string object from a C-style string).

There were a number of methods devised for handling conversion to bool more safely. One was converting to `void *` instead, which prevented some problems, but not others (this was used by iostreams). There was also a "safe bool" idiom (actually, more like a "safe bool" theme, of which there were several variations). While these certainly improved control over what conversions would and wouldn't be allowed, most of them involved a fair amount of overhead (a typical safe bool required a base class of ~50 lines of code, plus derivation from that base class, etc.)

As to how explicit conversion and contextual conversion would help, the basic idea is pretty simple. You can (starting with C++11) mark a conversion function as `explicit`, which allows it to be used only where an explicit cast to the target type is used:

```
struct X {
    explicit operator bool() { return true; }
};

int main() { 
    X x;
    bool b1 = static_cast<bool>(x); // compiles
    bool b2 = x;   // won't compile
}
```

Contextual conversion adds a little to let the conversion to bool happen implicitly, but *only* in something like an `if` statement, so using a class with the conversion function above, you'd get:

```
X x;
if (x) // allowed

int y = x; // would require explicit cast to compile
```

I'd add that complaints about "orthogonality" seem quite inapplicable here. Although *convenient*, converting a string to a Boolean doesn't really make a lot of sense. If anything, we should complain about how strange it is for `string("0")` to convert to `1` (in languages where that happens).

Answer (score 11):

[This article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2333.html) mentions some reasons why `operator bool()` can lead to surprising results.

Note that `std::string` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. There is also `std::wstring` for multi-byte characters. An implicit conversion would let you write:

```
std::string foo = "foo";
std::wstring bar = "bar";
if (foo == bar) {
  std::cout << "This will be printed, because both are true!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::string` still has to coexist with C-style strings.

A C-style string is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character", and is generally accessed via a pointer to its first character. An expression such as `"hello, world"` is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the first character. Such a pointer may then be implicitly converted to `bool`, yielding `true` if the pointer is non-null, `false` if it's null. (In C, it's not converted to `bool`, but it can still be used directly as a condition, so the effect is nearly the same.)

So, due to C++'s C heritage, if you write:

```
if ("") { ... }
```

the empty string is already treated as `true`, and that couldn't easily be changed without breaking C compatibility.

I suggest that having a C-style empty string evaluate as `true` and a C++ empty `std::string` evaluate as `false` would be too confusing.

And writing `if (!s.empty())` isn't *that* difficult (and IMHO it's more legible).

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to what you (and I) want, that I've been able to find, is the following.

You can define the `!` operator on `std::string's` like so:

```
bool operator!(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.empty();
}
```

This allows you to do:

```
std::string s;
if (!s)             // if `s` is empty
```

And using a simple negation, you can do:

```
if (!!s)            // if `s` is not empty
```

That's a little awkward, but the question is, how badly do you want to avoid extra characters? `!strcmp(...)` is awkward, too, but we still functioned and got used to it, and many of us preferred it because it was faster than typing `strcmp(...) == 0`.

If anyone discovers a way to do `if (s)`, in C++, please let us know.