# Why implicit conversion of bool to string isn't an error?

Tags: c++, string, boolean, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

I goggled it & tried to find similar question on SO also but didn't find anything useful. So, posting my question here.

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(const std::string &) {}
int main() 
{
    foo(false);
}
```

```
[Warning] converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 1 of 'std::basic_string::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]' [-Wconversion-null]
```

Why C++ allows this without explicit cast? I was expecting to get compiler error. The program abnormally terminates at runtime due to exception displaying following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What the standard says about this type of implicit conversion?

Comment: "What the standard says about this type of implicit conversion? " It says it is allowed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No. It's not like that. you need to write relevant text from the C++ standard.

Comment: @Downvoters: why downvotes? What's wrong in question?

Comment: it's interesting that foo(true) causes a compile-time error

Comment: on gcc, for example: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/axWuSF1Nalk1Gr74. maybe the reason is that `false` can be implicilty casted to `const char*` as null pointer.

Comment: Rather, I should have said "it is allowed before C++11".

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226967/why-stdstring-is-not-implicitly-converted-to-bool)

Comment: @juanchopanza: In C++14 compiler, it also terminates abnormally, see this: http://ideone.com/OArT89

Comment: It would be better if someone writes in their answer how this program's behavior is different in C++03 & C++11?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I am not talking about terminating. I'm talking about compilation. If it compiles, then you should expect an abnormal termination, because that is what happens when you instantiate a string from the null pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before C++11 introduced the `nullptr` keyword, null pointers were a bit of a  hack. Any integer literal equal to zero would suffice as a null pointer constant, and `false` fit the bill.

So, the effect of your program is to construct the `std::string` with a `char const *` argument of `NULL`. The constructor doesn't support null pointers, so you get undefined behavior.

The solution to this problem is to use a newer dialect of C++. Pass `-std=c++11` to the compiler if necessary, or `-std=c++14`. Then you should get something like this:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
> ```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f3048229a1d0e5a

**EDIT:** Hmm, GCC doesn't appear to implement this change yet. That's a bit surprising. You might try Clang.

I've [filed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67216) a bug report.

Comment: GCC still compiles it with C++11 or C++14 enabled.

Comment: @Quentin, it issues a diagnostic, which is technically all that is required for an ill-formed program. I'd prefer if it was an error not a warning though.

Comment: @JonathanWakely But what about SFINAE and overload partial ordering? I'm lazy to test with a specific example now, sorry.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: ya, it issues a diagnosis. But wouldn't it nice if it also issue a compiler error like clang? Should I file a bug report?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I lied, not so lazy. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67216

Comment: @PravasiMeet an implementation is free to provide extensions that give a meaning to ill-formed programs, so GCC is still conforming. Edit: forget that : Potatoswatter's example shows that it is indeed a bug, since it modifies the interpretation of a well-formed program.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Thanks for filing a bug report. Can you please add my name into that report? I would be glad if you do so.

Comment: @PravasiMeet Get a login there and add yourself to the CC list. The bug database is tied to a mailing list server, so comments there can't be edited.

Comment: FWIW, 6 month later and gcc 5.3, bug still there.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that an `std::string` is implicitly constructed from `false`, using the `const CharT*` overload and converting `false` to a null pointer. According to the documentation for that constructor :

> The behavior is undefined if `s` [the pointer] does not point at an array of at least `Traits::length(s)+1` elements of `CharT`.

Hence the malfunctioning (in the form of a friendly exception, but don't rely on it).

Now, is it correct ? According to [conv.ptr] :

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

`false` has indeed a value of zero, but is not an integer literal (it's a boolean literal). The implicit conversion to the `CharT*` that `std::string`'s constructor takes is thus non-standard.

And indeed, while GCC emits a warning, Clang refuses to compile it.

Comment: Clang compiles it if you specify `-std=c++03`. It just depends which dialect is the default for the particular compiler version.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But the question does not mention C++03. In C++11 and beyond, only the literal `0` can be converted to a null pointer.

Comment: @Quentin: why you saying that don't rely on the form of friendly exception?

Comment: @PravasiMeet the standard does not define any behaviour if the requirement for `s` to point at an actual array is not fulfilled. The resulting program is free to do nothing, crash, throw exceptions or anything else. Your standard library implementor decided to throw an exception in that case, which is nice in a sense (better than corrupting memory), but isn't guaranteed to behave the same on other implementations. I do wonder why this is an exception and not an assertion though.

Comment: @Quentin: ok got it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A bool is basically an integer so it will be interpreted as a zero ,in your case it is probablly the 0 character and this will cause that problem the string will an exception