# std::string initialization with a bool

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, stdstring, clang++

Consider the following initialization:

```
std::string falseString = false;
std::string trueString = true;
```

With `g++ 5.2.0`, compiler throws a warning for `falseString`, while an error for `trueString`.

With `clang++ 3.6 -std=c++11`, compiler throws error for both `falseString` as well as `trueString`.

Q1) Why the different behavior with `gcc` even though both initialization values are of the same type (`bool`)?

Q2) Which compiler is correct and why? What does the standard say?

EDIT:

> error: no viable conversion from 'bool' to 'std::string' (aka
>   'basic_string')
>
> warning: converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 1 of
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
>   _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]'
>   [-Wconversion-null]

Comment: Telling us what the warnings/errors are might be a clue...? Did you omit them deliberately?

Comment: Mainly historical - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009694/why-implicit-conversion-of-bool-to-string-isnt-an-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, you definitely cannot initialise a `std::string` from `true`. That's just nonsensical.

GCC 5.2 is accepting the initialisation from `false`, with protest, because it used to be a valid null pointer literal. Yeah. Compare 3.9.1/6 between C++03 and C++11 — "as described below, bool values behave as integral types" was removed.

It should error on both compilers these days, but [GCC was buggy in this regard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010054/560648) until like a month ago (so GCC 6.0).

Comment: So it was a bug as expected!