# Assigning a number to std::string is now allowed?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string foo;
    foo = -1; // why is the compiler not complaining about this?
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

Actual output (both ideone.com C++14 mode and GCC 4.8.4):

```
<no output>
```

Questions:

1. Why did the code snippet compile at all?
2. Commenting out `foo = -1`, I get the correct stdout (`1` and `2`). What has the compiler compiled with `foo = -1;` that causes the subsequent `cout`s to fail?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563648/stdstring-initialization-with-a-bool

Comment: Because there are no constructors which accepts integers for the string container. Either you make your implementation or use string-ed numbers.

Comment: @Joel But why does assignment accept it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ char is not the same integer in the way you can make math operations.

Comment: If you're surprised by that, consider that `foo = 'a';` also works, [with good reason](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D).

Comment: @Joel `char` is a perfect integral numeric type.

Comment: same thing gave me a output `ÿ` , must be a junk character

Comment: @piyushjaiswal In Windows-1252 codepage, `255` represents character `ÿ`. But why `255` would be used instead of `-1` is completely unclear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foo = -1;
```

resolves to `std::string::operator=(char)` since `-1` is an `int` and `int` can, in theory, be converted to a `char`.

It's not clear to me what the standard says when the `int` does not represent a valid `char`. It looks like in your implementation, the program crashes.

**Update**

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types**
>
> 1 Objects declared as characters (`char`) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation’s basic character set. If a character from this set is stored in a character object, the integral value of that character
>   object is equal to the value of the single character literal form of that character. **It is implementation-defined whether a char object can hold negative values.**

It appears that you'll have to consult your compiler's documentation to understand whether it allows `char` object to hold negative values and, if it does, how does it treat such objects.

Comment: What's an invalid `char`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, rephrased that part.

Comment: I suppose it missinterprets the -1 as an EOF

Comment: Still not clear. -1, as far as I'm aware, is a perfectly valid value for a `char`. Even if `char` is unsigned, the conversion is well defined.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, added some info from the standard to my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: true - the big question is probably nothing to do with C++; rather, what the specific terminal in use chooses to do when sent a `(char)-1`... given nothing further was seen, it might have gone into some escape sequence mode, change the foreground colour to X coincidentally matching the background, suspended the foreground process, tried to switch to an unavailable font, hung or crashed etc....  piyush jaiswal comments he got a umlauted "y" - as reasonable as anything.

Comment: @TonyD "what the specific terminal in use chooses to do" theoretically anything, but in practice this doesn't happen with terminals known to science.

Comment: @n.m. the OP reports "<no output>" - seemingly from any of his 3 lines of code, which if true would mean something this outlandish must be happening.  But, given he was running on ideone.com (which I can't access on this device), it could be the actual output got jumbled up or rejected by some HTML encoding logic on the site.

Answer (score 5):

`char` is an integral type in C++. `std::string` defines an assignment operator:

```
std::string& operator=(char);
```

Since `int` converts to `char` freely in this context, no diagnostic is given. (It's funny how best intentions pave the road to Hell, innit?)

<s>Since `(char)-1` is probably not a valid member if the execution character set on your platform, the stream enters an error state and will stay there, outputting nothing, until the error bit is cleared.</s>

EDIT this is a bug of ideone. If the output stream contains an "illegal" character, the entire stream is not shown, even the parts produced and flushed before the bad character. Use another online compiler to check.

Comment: So `foo = -1;` sets the stream to an error state? Exception being an integral part of C++, I fail to see why it still uses a silent "error state" mechanism.

Comment: @ZachSaw you can set up iostreams to throw exceptions, but it's not the default.

Comment: @ZachSaw [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180268/why-are-c-stl-iostreams-not-exception-friendly).

Comment: `cout << char(-1)` is not going to put the stream in any error state: streams are capable of transporting arbitrary binary content.  It may "screw up" the terminal software that tries to render that character code (see my comment under R Sahu's answer).

Comment: @TonyD "streams are capable of transporting arbitrary binary content." When you use binary output functions such as `ostream::write`. Have you tried to call a firmatted output with an invalid character on Windows? Please report your findings.

Comment: @n.m. I have many times, and just did it again with VS2013 as a sanity check on my feeble old memory: works perfectly.  Just loop doing `cout << c` for all values 0 to 255, redirect it to a file, and e.g. cygwin `less` can show you all character codes captured as expected.

Comment: If you look at the `operator<<` docs, the relevance of `<<` being a formatted output function is just in the potential padding if `setw()` had been used, which wouldn't happen for `put()` or `write()`....

Comment: @TonyD I cannot check it right now (no Windows machine at hand) but I do remember quite well VC++ refusing to output "illegal" characters. Can you try to output it to the console window?

Comment: @n.m. for my CMD.EXE on Win7, it displays the same character set you can see [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Codepage-850.png), except the "spades" suit character (ASCII 6) through single quaver (ASCII 12) aren't visible, ASCII 14 onwards appear on the next line, and it otherwise wraps at the 80th column.

Comment: @TonyD nevermind, this is not the situation OP observes. See my edited answer.

Comment: @n.m. you should ditch the *"Since (char)-1 is probably not a valid member if the execution character set on your platform, the stream enters an error state and will stay there, outputting nothing, until the error bit is cleared."* then - it's misleading....

Answer (score 1):

These are the operator= overloads for the string class :-

```
basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& str);
basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& str) noexcept(allocator_traits<Allocator>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value ||     allocator_traits<Allocator>::is_always_equal::value);
basic_string& operator=(const charT* s);
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
basic_string& operator=(initializer_list<charT>);
```

Hope that makes sense why that compiled fine.

Now coming onto your question as to why there is no output. I have tweaked the code a little :-

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string foo;
    foo = -1; // why is the compiler not complaining about this?
    char ch = 65;
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    //change ch to -1 ... ascii
    ch = -1;
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

Can you guess what the output is ? Yup think in terms of ascii :-

```
1
 
A
 
2
```

That's exactly the reason why you don't have the output for -1.

Compiler - MinGW - std=c++14 -- not sure why IDEONE messes up the complete output stream in your case.