# Does implementation-definedness of char affect std::string?

Tags: c++

I thought all types were signed unless otherwise specified (like `int`). I was surprised to find that for `char` it's actually implementation-defined:

> ... It is implementation-defined whether a char object can hold
>   negative values. ... In any particular implementation, a plain `char`
>   object can take on either the same values as a `signed char` or an
>   `unsigned char`; which one is implementation-defined.

However `std::string` is really just `std::basic_string<char, ...>`.

Can the semantics of this program change from implementation?

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char c = -1;
    std::string s{1, c};
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does affect semantics of `std::sring`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by the semantics changing?

Comment: Can you be specific? @SergeyA

Comment: That is all preconditions are met and all effects are exactly the same regardless of whether char is signed or unsigned. @juanchopanza

Comment: @user6331143 The program doesn't do anything, so yes, you could say the semantics are unchanged.

Comment: @user6331143, I am as specific as your question is. Yes, since char can be signed or unsigned, std::string elements can be signed or unsigned. It would affect arithmetics and promotions on them, for example.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202036/assigning-a-number-to-stdstring-is-now-allowed.

Comment: @RSahu That's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177704/why-does-c-allow-an-integer-to-be-assigned-to-a-string)

Comment: In the old days, the designers of C gave priority to what the machines supported natively, as being the most efficient, at the expense of portability.

Comment: Yes it changes things but it really should not matter for you.  You should use characters like `'a'` and not there values when working with strings.  This makes the code portable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Since a `std::string` contains objects of type `char`, the signedness of type `char` can affect its behavior.

The program in your question:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char c = -1;
    std::string s{1, c};
}
```

has no visible behavior (unless terminating without producing any output is "behavior"), so its behavior doesn't depend on the signedness of plain `char`. A compiler could reasonably optimize out the entire body of `main`. (I'm admittedly nitpicking here, commenting on the code example you picked rather than the question you're asking.)

But this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "xx";
    s[0] = -1;
    s[1] = +1;
    std::cout << "Plain char is " << (s[0] < s[1] ? "signed" : "unsigned") << "\n";
}
```

will correctly print either `Plain char is signed` or `Plain char is unsigned`.

Note that a similar program that compares two `std::string` objects using that type's `operator<` does *not* distinguish whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned, since `<` treats the characters as if they were unsigned, similar to the way C's `memcmp` works.

But this shouldn't matter 99% of the time. You almost certainly have to go out of your way to write code whose behavior depends on the signedness of `char`. You should keep in mind that it's implementation-defined, but if the signedness matters, you should be using `signed char` or (more likely) `unsigned char` explicitly. `char` is a numeric type, but you should use it to hold character data.