# Conversion of false to object via const char * constructor

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have built the following minimal example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(const char *s);

    private:
        const char *p;
};

A::A(const char *s)
  : p(s)
{
}

A foo()
{
    return false;
}

A bar()
{
    return true;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2` I get the following:

```
t.cc: In function 'A foo()':
t.cc:17:10: warning: converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 1 of 'A::A(const char*)' [-Wconversion-null]
t.cc: In function 'A bar()':
t.cc:23:10: error: could not convert 'true' from 'bool' to 'A'
```

As far as I know, it is possible to use one type `T` instead of an instance of class `A`, if class `A` has a constructor `A(T)`. In this case, the value / instance of T is wrapped by the compiler inside a call to the `A(T)` constructor.

Also, only one direct implicit conversion is allowed, i.e. no chain `A(B(c))` is inserted to convert a value `c` of type `C`, even if constructors `A(B)` and `B(C)` exist.

So, my questions:

1. Why is `false` converted to a pointer in my example? Sure, a pointer is not an object, but there are still two implicit conversions here. What rule is being applied?
2. Why does the conversion not work with `true`? My intuition is that `false` can be reasonably converted to a `nullptr` (see also the warning), whereas there is no meaningful pointer value for `true`.

So, could someone explain what conversion rules apply / do not apply to the two examples above?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. All zero-valued integral objects (to which both `bool` and `char` belong) can be implicitly converted to `nullptr`. That's why `int* x = 0;` (and `int* x = '\0';`) works, but `int* x = 1;` does not.

Comment: Good question really !!!

Answer (score 5):

As published, C++ 11 has the rule "an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type which evaluates to `0` can be converted to any pointer type, yielding the null pointer value of that type." (C++98/03 had a similarly worded rule with the same net effect).

`bool` is an integer type, and `false` evaluates to `0`. So `false` is a valid null pointer constant.

Apart from this extra rule, C++ has no implicit conversions from integral types to pointers. Which is why `true` cannot implicitly be converted to a pointer.

However, C++14 changed the definition of a null pointer constant so that only integer literals (and not integral constant expressions) qualify. `false` is a boolean literal, not an integer one, so under C++14, the code will not compile.

Furthermore, since the issue was recognised by the standard committee as a defect in C++11, newer C++11 compilers are likely to obey the C++14 rules in this regard and not treat `false` as a null pointer constant. Thanks to [@Destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3777958/destructor) for tracking down the [issue status](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903).

---

As to why two implicit conversions seem to be allowed here: the rule is not "at most one implicit conversion is allowed." The rule is "at most one **user-defined** conversion is allowed." Pointer conversions (such as converting a null pointer constant to a null pointer value) are not classified as user-defined conversions. So the conversion sequence in your case is a pointer conversion (`bool` to `const char *`) followed by a user-defined conversion (`const char *` to `A`).

Comment: What about the rule that only one implicit conversion should be allowed? In my first example there are two of them: boolean false to `const char *`, and `const char *` to `A`.

Comment: @Giorgio Yes, as the answer says. It is a prvalue of an integral type (which is synonymous with integer type) which evaluates to `0`.

Comment: @Angew: program shouldn't compile since C++11 & later standards. It is invalid C++ program. See my answer !!!

Comment: @Destructor The compilers seem to agree with you, but can you explain why it's no longer valid in C++11? I can't seem to read the standard in a way which would prevent the `false` -> null pointer conversion.

Comment: @Angew: My bad. I also can't seem to read the standard in a way which would prevent the false -> null pointer conversion. But rules seems to be definitely changed since C++11 that's why compiler gives errors. If you find that standard citation please tell me also.

Comment: @Angew: read this: https://www.quora.com/Where-does-the-C++-standard-says-that-false-to-null-pointer-conversion-is-not-allowed-since-C++11

Answer (score 2):

The OP 's program fails in compilation in g++ & clang++ when use `-std=c++11`,      `-std=c++14`.

See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DbV4qu0qllkMJh4Z) on g++ 6.1.0. It gives following error

```
prog.cc: In function 'A foo()':
prog.cc:17:12: error: could not convert 'false' from 'bool' to 'A'
     return false;
            ^~~~~
```

See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb3299e6197ca2ca) on clang++. It gives following diagnosis.

```
main.cpp:17:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'bool' to function return type 'A'
    return false;
           ^~~~~
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'const A &' for 1st argument
class A
      ^
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'A &&' for 1st argument
class A
      ^
main.cpp:10:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
A::A(const char *s)
   ^
main.cpp:22:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'bool' to function return type 'A'
    return true;
           ^~~~
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'const A &' for 1st argument
class A
      ^
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'A &&' for 1st argument
class A
      ^
main.cpp:10:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
A::A(const char *s)
   ^
main.cpp:7:21: warning: private field 'p' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
        const char *p;
                    ^
```

**false** should not convert to pointer type since C++11. See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009694/why-implicit-conversion-of-bool-to-string-isnt-an-error) which I've asked sometimes ago.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), `false` is of type `bool`, and it can be [**promoted**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to an `int` implicitely:

> - the type `bool` can be converted to `int` with the value `false` becoming ​`0`​ and `true` becoming `1`.

So, `false` is basically promoted to `NULL`/`0` (or `nullptr`), which can be assigned to a pointer.

For 2), §4.10 states that:

> A **null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.
>
> **A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type**; [...]

Only a `Null pointer constant` can be converted to a pointer, and a null pointer constant is either an intergral with value `0` or `std::nullptr_t`. `true` (or `1` for that matter) aren't specified, and thus they can't be converted to a pointer.

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Comment: You may take your throne, Lightness. This game is yours.