# std::stoi alternatives for boolean

Tags: c++, string, casting, std

Are there a `std::stoi` for `bool` type in C++? I can only find this conversion for `double`, `float`, `int` and `long`

the input is coming from a `std::to_string(some_bool_value)`

Comment: how would you want to parse the `bool`? ('0' & '1' / 'true' & 'false')

Comment: @Amachi: My answer to that would be in the same way that `bool b; std::istringstream(your string here) >> std::boolalpha >> b;` does. In other words the C++ standard already has the concept of a stringification of the `bool` values.

Comment: @Bathsheba regarding to the documentation of `std::boolalpha` the case of 0 / 1 is not respected, but rather its representation `true` / `false`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from a std::string to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165921/converting-from-a-stdstring-to-bool)

Comment: @Amachi: Yes that makes sense to me.

Comment: @BalázsÁrva: Nice spot. Needless to say, I prefer the answer with the most votes on that page! (I don't like the accepted answer - if you want to convert a stringified number to a `bool` then use stoi and friends and assign the result to a `bool`).

Comment: edited the question to give more context about the origin of the string

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. I guess it's down to somebody to convince the C++ standards committee of its necessity.

It could be consistent with the built-in

```
bool b;
std::istringstream("true") >> std::boolalpha >> b;
```

so the possible string contents (probably the most contentious point) could be limited to that.

Comment: in case can i use `std::stoi` and then `static_cast<bool>` it?

Comment: @Berto99: If you want to convert a stringified number to a `bool`, then use one of the `std::stoi` type functions, and assign the result to a `bool` type.

Comment: @Amachi: We can't see that - but if it's an answer then do put it as a new answer rather than a comment here.

Comment: @Bathsheba  i just wanted to say the same as already explained. `std::stoi` and then cast back to a bool. Be aware that if you have the input `-1` it will count as true as well!

Comment: the fact that it comes from `std::to_string` si compatible with the first comment?